# What's the specific permission to allow an AWS IAM group access to change an S3 object's metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, user-permissions

I want to grant an AWS IAM group permission to upload, view, modify, and delete objects in a single bucket, through the Management Console. I've got most of it down, but I'm getting reports that users in that group are **unable to modify object metadata** - they're getting the "Sorry! You were denied access to do that!" dialog.

Here's the policy I have:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1403204838000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1403205082000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1403205119000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know which S3 action(s) I need to assign to allow the group access to modify object properties (specifically, the metadata)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object metadata is covered by the GetObject action.  For versioned objects you would instead use GetObjectVersion.  So the policies you have listed should be working for accessing metadata.  There's a great summary of all the permissions and what each one covers [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html) in the AWS docs.

If you're able to recreate the error using the AWS REST interface instead of the web console you can get more detailed error information. Using a tool like [this perl command line utility](http://timkay.com/aws/) can be useful in that regard.  Using this you can determine the specific [S3 error codes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) that you don't typically see when using their web console.  Knowing the specific error that's causing the problem will go a long way to determining why the users can't edit the metadata despite your having the correct policies in place.

Comment: Ok, I've gotten the utility you linked to working. It lists the buckets I have successfully. However, I have no clue how to use it to try to modify the metadata of a file. I looked through the docs but they only references to "metadata" seem to be in connection with copying or moving a file. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

Just did a long process of elimination and found that this was the least I could get away with for command line and console updating metadata:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
        "Condition": {}
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
        "Condition": {}
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {}
    }
]
```

}